# iOS - NSAttributedString tokenized to localization.string element

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring, localizable.strings

I have created a html attributed string like this:

```
NSString * htmlString = @"<html><body> Some html string <sup>MD</sup></body></html>";
NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
```

Now i have a localized string that has a token like this:

```
"greeting_label" ="reeveBeets%s \n are awesome";
```

how do i replace the %s with my attributed html text i created and put it in a label i have as a iboutlet called _label ?

Comment: Also, IBOutlets aren't ivars, because of this, an IBOutlet should never be pre pended with a _. You label should be named label, not _label.

Comment: xcode synthesised it for me.  so in my .h file its called label but when i use it in code i use _label. what do you think?

Comment: Yeah that's ok, it's preferred to use self.property everywhere that doesn't involve an instance variable, getter/setter side effects, init or dealloc. But it's ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Localized formatted strings work just like regular formatted strings as you can see in the example below:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"nearby_station", nil), self.endStation.name]
```

Where

```
"nearby_station" = "Nearby %@ Station";
```

Comment: thats not really what i want.  I want to insert a NSAttributedString in the token you have. ie the %@. So am i able to do this is teh question: [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"nearby_station", nil), someAttributedString]

Comment: Well, the best I can give is to tell you that you'll have to create an attributed string an manually insert one attributed string into another. You can do this via appending and attributed string or adding/removing attributes of an attributed string from one attributed string to another. Once you've generated your attributed string, you have access to all of your properties. I will repeat that the above is the exact same thing as stringWithFormat, so anything you can do with that you can do with this (and you cannot just inject an attributed string into that).

Comment: You should also change your question to reflect what you want better.

Comment: You'll want to find the index of %s in your string and perform: 
- insertAttributedString:atIndex: from NSMutableAttributedString